# How to add Custom Attributes to a DynamicMethod-generated method?

Tags: c#, .net, custom-attributes, dynamicmethod

I was playing around with [`DynamicMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod.aspx) and [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)' [Compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362.aspx) (which uses `DynamicMethod` internally).

I then wondered if there is a way to add a custom attribute to the generated method. I googled about it, but I couldn't find a way. I know that it's possible to do using CodeDom, but I want to use `DynamicMethod`.

Someone mentioned [Type Descriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171819.aspx), but I'm not sure if it helps.

Does anyone knows a way to define custom attributes to methods generated using `DynamicMethod`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No there is no way to set custom attributes on DynamicMethods, [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod.aspx):

> Custom attributes are not supported on
>   dynamic methods or their parameters.