# Why does DynamicMethod.DefineParameter always return null?

Tags: c#

I Would like to generate the following method using [DynamicMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
public string HelloWorld([CustomAttribute]string name)
{
    return name;
}
```

I have tried the following but DefineParameter always returns null. How can I assign my custom attribute to the parameter.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var method = new DynamicMethod("HelloWorld", typeof (string), new[] {typeof (string)});

        var parameterBuilder = method.DefineParameter(1, ParameterAttributes.In, "text");
        parameterBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(new CustomAttributeBuilder(typeof(CustomAttribute).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes), new object[] {}));

        var il = method.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        var temp = (Func<string,string>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof (Func<string, string>));
        Console.WriteLine(temp("Hello World"));
    }
}

public class CustomAttribute : Attribute
{        
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add Custom Attributes to a DynamicMethod-generated method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145123/how-to-add-custom-attributes-to-a-dynamicmethod-generated-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know *why* but on the page you link to, the docs say it is not supported:

> Dynamic methods and their parameters do not have to be named, but you can specify names to assist in debugging. Custom attributes are not supported on dynamic methods or their parameters.